# How to run websockets in two ports in laravel?

Tags: laravel-8

How to run two different ports like 6001 and 3030 in same server it is causing spawn error can anyone help me how to do using Laravel??

Answer (score 0):

You can check [right here](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/issues/262) the way of declaring the port number. Since the 6001 is the default port, you can opt to declare it or not.